# On Change event to for ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I want to bind the following function to any changes on my CKEditor textarea. I am currently using version 4.2. I added the onChange CKEditor plugin but my issue is I cannot seem to bind to the formUnloadPrompt().

Here is my jQuery function:

```
function formUnloadPrompt(formSelector) {
    var formA = $(formSelector).serialize(), formB, formSubmit = false;

    // Detect Form Submit
    $(formSelector).submit( function(){
        formSubmit = true;
    });

    // Handle Form Unload
    window.onbeforeunload = function(){
        if (formSubmit) return;
        formB = $(formSelector).serialize();
        if (formA != formB) return "Your changes have not been saved.";
    };

    // Enable & Disable Submit Button
    var formToggleSubmit = function(){
        formB = $(formSelector).serialize();
        $(formSelector+' [type="submit"]').attr( "disabled", formA == formB);
    };

    formToggleSubmit();
    $(formSelector).change(formToggleSubmit);
    $(formSelector).keyup(formToggleSubmit);
}

$(function(){
    formUnloadPrompt('#form');
});
```

My CKEditor code

```
CKEDITOR.instances['frm_content'].on( 'change', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
    var inst = CKEDITOR.instances['frm_content'];
    if (inst.getData() != '') {
        $('[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $(' [type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```